# Disable Fullpage cache for specific controller in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I've a route where build a payload and submit it to some other site,

like this

```
[
  ...
  'hash' => 'MD5_HASH_FOR_THIS_PAYLOAD' 

]
```

But the problem is the the data is being cached by magento 2nd time when I visit this route magento sends the request the old payload,

I tried the following code in controller's `execute` method

```
 <?php 
 $cacheManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Manager');
 $types = array('full_page');
 $cacheManager->flush($types);
```

but didn't worked for me.

### Edit

I don't have xml layout for this page and have just a single block which is created by the controller

```
 $block = $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\MyBlock');
 $block->setCacheable(false);
```

Can someone please help me how can I exclude this route from FPC.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose your specific page has it's layout with templates & blocks?

Magento's caching of pages is using the block information. If a page has only cachable blocks then magento will consider that the page can be cached.

Just add the `cacheable="false"` in the  layout for the block of the page that needs to be dynamic. Empty caches and magento should do the rest.

So your block in the layout should be like :

```
<block class="..." name="my_custom_block" as="custom" template="..." cacheable="false"/>
```

If you don't use layout but instead created the block dynamically, then you can simple set the cache_lifetime on your block in the _construct method :

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => null));
}
```

I don't think creating blocks directly in the controller dynamically is good practice.

Comment: I don't have a layout but have a single block which is created dynamically in `execute` method of controller. I've updated the question with that code as well.

Comment: I just updated my response to add what you need to add to your block.

Comment: For me addData() throws an error that the method is undefined

Answer (score 3):

In addition to manipulating the cacheability of the block, remember that in some instances, such as appending a body to default response, the controller response could possibly be cached by itself. Meaning that no matter what you define to the block the caches will not be disabled. To get around the issue you can define `Cache-Control Headers` for the response you're sending back. See the following example from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html#disable-caching

```
public function execute()
{
    $page = $this->pageFactory->create();

    //We are using HTTP headers to control various page caches (varnish, fastly, built-in php cache)
    $page->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', true);

    return $page;
}
```

In Magento 2.2.2 Cache-Control can be set to the default `$this->getResponse()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a cache key that is unique per search query.

Create a plugin for the topmenu block in `di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
    <plugin name="topmenu_searchbar" type="Vendor\Package\Plugin\Block\Topmenu" />
</type>
```

Then use the `getAfterCacheKeyInfo()` method:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Package\Plugin\Block;

class Topmenu
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Search\Helper\Data
     */
    private $searchHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Search\Helper\Data $searchHelper
    ) {
        $this->searchHelper = $searchHelper;
    }

    /**
     * Since the search bar was moved into the topnav, we need to add a key for the search term
     * so it doesn't get cached.
     */
     public function afterGetCacheKeyInfo(\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject, $result)
     {
         $result[] = $subject->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, 'q' => $this->searchHelper->getEscapedQueryText()]);
         return $result;
     }
}
```